# Different results for polynomial regression in R and Python

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to reproduce a piece of python code in R. This code uses the `fit_transform()` function from the `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` package and I'm not understanding why R's `poly()` function is not outputting the same results. Does anyone know how to achieve the same number of the python code in R and why `poly()` is not returning the same results as `fit_transform()`?

**R Code**

```r
poly(c(17:25),4, simple = TRUE)
```

**R output**

```
               1          2             3          4
 [1,] -0.5163978  0.5318160 -4.449492e-01  0.3128931
 [2,] -0.3872983  0.1329540  2.224746e-01 -0.4693397
 [3,] -0.2581989 -0.1519474  4.131671e-01 -0.2458446
 [4,] -0.1290994 -0.3228883  2.860388e-01  0.2011456
 [5,]  0.0000000 -0.3798686  2.352347e-17  0.4022911
 [6,]  0.1290994 -0.3228883 -2.860388e-01  0.2011456
 [7,]  0.2581989 -0.1519474 -4.131671e-01 -0.2458446
 [8,]  0.3872983  0.1329540 -2.224746e-01 -0.4693397
 [9,]  0.5163978  0.5318160  4.449492e-01  0.3128931
```

**Python Code**

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
foo = np.array([range(17,26)]).reshape(-1,1)
print(poly.fit_transform(foo))
```

**Python Output**

```py
[[1.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 2.89000e+02 4.91300e+03 8.35210e+04]
 [1.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 3.24000e+02 5.83200e+03 1.04976e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 3.61000e+02 6.85900e+03 1.30321e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 4.00000e+02 8.00000e+03 1.60000e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 4.41000e+02 9.26100e+03 1.94481e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 4.84000e+02 1.06480e+04 2.34256e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 5.29000e+02 1.21670e+04 2.79841e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 5.76000e+02 1.38240e+04 3.31776e+05]
 [1.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 6.25000e+02 1.56250e+04 3.90625e+05]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I needed to do was setting `raw = TRUE` in the R's `poly()` function to bring the raw and not orthogonal polynomials. R's output is in common notation and sklearn's output is in scientific notation.